# Invalid object name when creating stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure on SQL Server 2008.  Whenever I try to execute the procedure I get an Invalid object name error on the #EDPTS table.  Can someone please take a look at the below code to let me know what might be creating the issue?  Thank you in advance

```
use maindb
go 
CREATE PROCEDURE DailyStats
AS

set transaction isolation level read uncommitted

DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE, @ENDDATE DATE
SET @ENDDATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
SET @STARTDATE = DATEADD(DAY,-1, @ENDDATE)


if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EDPTS')is not null
drop table #EDPTS

SELECT DISTINCT PV.[EID]
  ,ENC.PERSON_ID
  ,PV.[VisitNumber]
  ,ENC.MRN
  ,PER.NAME_FULL_FORMATTED as 'PTName'
  ,PER.SEX_CD_DESCR as 'Gender'
  ,CONVERT(varchar,PER.BIRTH_DT_TM,101)as 'DOB'
  ,DATEDIFF (YEAR,PER.BIRTH_DT_TM,ENC.ARRIVE_DT_TM)as 'ArrivalAge'
  ,MIN (CHIN.CHECKIN_DT_TM) as 'EDArrival'
  ,ENC.ADMIT_MODE_CD_DESCR
  ,ENC.REASON_FOR_VISIT as 'ChiefComp'
  ,[PatientClass]
  ,ACCOMMODATION_CD_DESCR as 'Accommodation'
  ,[AssignedPatientLocationFacility]
  ,[AdmitSourceDescr]
  ,[FinancialClass]
  ,CHIN.CHECKOUT_DISPOSITION_CD_DESCR as 'DCDispo'
  ,CASE WHEN MAX (CHIN.CHECKOUT_DT_TM) = '2100-12-31 00:00:00.000' then NULL ELSE MAX         (CHIN.CHECKOUT_DT_TM)END as 'EDDepart'
  ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF (minute,MIN(CHIN.CHECKIN_DT_TM),MAX(CHIN.CHECKOUT_DT_TM))> '1440'  then NULL ELSE
   DATEDIFF (minute,MIN(CHIN.CHECKIN_DT_TM),MAX(CHIN.CHECKOUT_DT_TM))END as 'EDLOS'
INTO #EDPTS
--finds ed pts
FROM tbl.one
with (nolock)
--more ed data
INNER JOIN tbl.two
with (nolock)
on PV.EID = ENC.EID 
--finds demographics
INNER JOIN tbl.three
with (nolock)
on ENC.PERSON_ID = PER.PERSON_ID
--finds ed discharge
LEFT Join tbl.four
with (nolock)
on ENC.EID = CHIN.EID


WHERE AdmissionType = '1'
and CHIN.CHECKIN_DT_TM between @STARTDATE and @ENDDATE
and AccountStatus <> 'CANCELLED
and chin.CHECKOUT_DISPOSITION_CD_DESCR <> 'Duplicate/Accidental Registration'
and enc.ENCNTR_CLASS_CD_DESCR <> 'Preadmit'
and ENC.ENCNTR_CLASS_CD_DESCR <> 'Limited Stay


GROUP BY PV.[EID]
  ,ENC.PERSON_ID
  ,PV.[VisitNumber]
  ,ENC.MRN
  ,PER.NAME_FULL_FORMATTED 
  ,PER.SEX_CD_DESCR
  ,CONVERT(varchar,PER.BIRTH_DT_TM,101)
  ,DATEDIFF (YEAR,PER.BIRTH_DT_TM,ENC.ARRIVE_DT_TM)
  ,ENC.ADMIT_MODE_CD_DESCR
  ,ENC.REASON_FOR_VISIT
  ,[PatientClass]
  ,ACCOMMODATION_CD_DESCR
  ,[AssignedPatientLocationFacility]
  ,[AdmitSourceDescr]
  ,[FinancialClass]
  ,CHECKOUT_DISPOSITION_CD_DESCR 

GO

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tri')is not null
drop table #Tri

SELECT  EVE.EID 
    ,MIN (CE.PERFORMED_DT_TM)as 'TriStart'
    ,MIN (EVE.COMPLETE_DT_TM) as 'TriComp'
    ,MAX(PRSNL.NAME_FULL_FORMATTED)  as 'TriNurse'

INTO #Tri
from tbl.one


GO

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tri2')is not null
drop table #Tri2

SELECT CE.EID 
  ,MAX(CE.RESULT_VAL) as 'Acuity

GROUP BY CE.EID 
GO

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EDBed')is not null
drop table #EDBed

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MDtoSee')is not null
drop table #MDtoSee

SELECT EVE.EID
  ,MIN (EVE.COMPLETE_DT_TM) as 'MDtoSee
SELECT #EDPTS.EID 
   ,#EDPTS.PERSON_ID 
   ,#EDPTS.VisitNumber 
   ,#EDPTS.AssignedPatientLocationFacility 
   ,#EDPTS.MRN
   ,#EDPTS.PTName
   ,#EDPTS.Gender
   ,#EDPTS.DOB 
   ,#EDPTS.ArrivalAge 
   ,MIN(#EDPTS.EDArrival)as EDArrival
   ,#EDPTS.ADMIT_MODE_CD_DESCR
   ,#EDPTS.ChiefComp 
   ,#EDPTS.AdmitSourceDescr
   ,#Tri2.Acuity
   ,#Tri.TriStart 
   ,#Tri.TriComp 
   ,DATEDIFF (minute,#EDPTS.EDArrival,#Tri.TriStart)
   ,DATEDIFF (minute,#Tri.TriStart,#Tri.TriComp)
   ,#Tri.TriNurse 
   ,#EDBed.EDBed 
   ,DATEDIFF (minute,#EDPTS.EDArrival,#EDBed.EDBed)
   ,#MDtoSee.MDtoSee 
   ,DATEDIFF (minute,#EDPTS.EDArrival,#MDtoSee.MDtoSee)
   ,#EDPTS.PatientClass 
   ,#EDPTS.FinancialClass 
   ,#EDPTS.Accommodation 
   ,#EDPTS.DCDispo 
   ,MAX(#EDPTS.EDDepart)as EDDepart
   ,#EDPTS.EDLOS 

 FROM #EDPTS with (nolock)LEFT JOIN #Tri with (nolock) on #EDPTS.EID = #Tri.EID 
 LEFT JOIN #Tri2 with (nolock) on #EDPTS.EID = #Tri2.EID 
 LEFT JOIN #EDBed with (nolock) on #EDPTS.EID = #EDBed.EID
 LEFT JOIN #MDtoSee with (nolock) on #EDPTS.EID = #MDtoSee.EID 
 GROUP BY #EDPTS.EID 
   ,#EDPTS.PERSON_ID 
   ,#EDPTS.VisitNumber 
   ,#EDPTS.AssignedPatientLocationFacility 
   ,#EDPTS.MRN
   ,#EDPTS.PTName
   ,#EDPTS.Gender
   ,#EDPTS.DOB 
   ,#EDPTS.ArrivalAge 
   ,#EDPTS.ADMIT_MODE_CD_DESCR
   ,#EDPTS.ChiefComp 
   ,#EDPTS.AdmitSourceDescr
   ,#Tri2.Acuity
   ,#Tri.TriStart 
   ,#Tri.TriComp 
   ,DATEDIFF (minute,#EDPTS.EDArrival,#Tri.TriStart)
   ,DATEDIFF (minute,#Tri.TriStart,#Tri.TriComp)
   ,#Tri.TriNurse 
   ,#EDBed.EDBed
```

Comment: what object is it saying is invalid... that would be important to know :)

Comment: Is it when you try to create it or when you call it? If it's on creation, run it again, double click the error message in the result panel and it should highlight the line the error is on. That would be useful.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that.  It is giving me an invalid object name on the temp table #EDPTS. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using NOLOCK on all your queries? Are they not important enough to require accurate data? That hint can and will return both missing and/or duplicate data.

Comment: Was told by admin that i should use nolock because a lot of other queries run off the same tables which can create a deadlock

Comment: Just to make sure we are clear. You were able to create the stored procedure but you cannot execute it? Or you can't run the create?

Comment: Can't run the create

Comment: Pretty sure your need to remove `GO` from between your selects. If you ran the above it probably created the stored procedure, ended that batch and then tried to run the select statements resulting in the error. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: JChao, it appears that did the trick.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GO` is causing the problem. It is ending the batch containing the `CREATE PROCEDURE`. Here's what is happening simplified.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Test1') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE test1

GO -- End batch

CREATE PROCEDURE Test1 
AS 
    IF Object_id('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL 
      DROP TABLE #temp

    SELECT 1 AS test 
    INTO   #temp

GO -- Ends the CREATE PROCEDURE batch

SELECT * 
FROM   #temp
```